# Set two separate xml view files to use the same code behind file

Tags: javascript, xml, nativescript

I have two Nativescript XML view files, one named `test.xml` and another named `test-rtl.xml`. I would like these views to share the same code behind file, for example `test.js`. Is this possible some how? I have heard in dev channels of the `Page` class containing a `codeFile` property but have not been able to find this property any where.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer by @dashman is the option you have.

Each page will have it's own page files(page.js, page.xml, page-view-model.js) What you can do is have both pages share the same model.js file. Create a shared folder and place the file in it. Just require it on the page you need it and bind it to the context and you are good to go.
You can find and example here: https://firebase.googleblog.com/2016/01/getting-started-with-nativescript-and_53.html

The user-view-model.js was used by both the login page and register page.

Answer (score 0):

Each file will have it's own page file...but what you can do is have both pages connect to the same context file. Then you can build the bulk of the page logic in that file. From the xml file, you can callback directly into the model file (e.g. tap="{{ tapEvent }}").